# how to fix " TypeError: MessageFilter.check_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update' "

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm using [python-telegram-bot V20.2](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/index.html)  to create somthing like this: **[Chat and User Selection](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#chat-and-user-selection)**

I'm having problem handling the event when the user shares a group/channel chat.

here is my code:

```
from telegram import Update, KeyboardButton, KeyboardButtonRequestChat, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, MessageHandler, filters


bot_token = "bot_token"


# python-telegram-bot setup
application = ApplicationBuilder().token(bot_token).build()

# python-telegram-bot command handler
async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    request_chat = KeyboardButtonRequestChat(1, True)
    keyboard = [[KeyboardButton("Request Chat", request_chat=request_chat)]]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text('Please share your contact details', reply_markup=reply_markup)



async def request_contact(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat = update.message.chat_shared
    if chat.request_id == 1:
        print(chat.chat_id)


application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters._Contact, request_contact)) #here is the problem!

print('Running...')
application.run_polling()
```

After I ran the bot, invoked the \start command, and shared a chat, I encountered this error:

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amin/anaconda3/envs/telegramBot/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1099, in process_update
    check = handler.check_update(update)  # Should the handler handle this update?
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/amin/anaconda3/envs/telegramBot/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_messagehandler.py", line 99, in check_update
    return self.filters.check_update(update) or False
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: MessageFilter.check_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `filters._Contact`, which is a protected class of the `filters` module. Those are not intended to be used by the user, but are for internal use of the `python-telegram-bot` library itself. See also [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance).
Please choose one of the filters documented [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#filters-module). I guess you'll want to use [`filters.StatusUpdate.CHAT_SHARED`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.StatusUpdate.CHAT_SHARED).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Is it possible to use this type of button and filter directly? I want to use the Telethon library, These features aren't available in the Telethon library yet. (I'm kind of new to the Telegram API, by the way.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "using this type of button and filter directly". Also I'm not very familiar with telethon.